# SQL Order By with LIMIT and OFFSET. SORT every matched rows at once

Tags: php, sql, query-optimization, limit

I want to create SQL sorting query with help of ORDER BY. I split result with LIMIT and OFFSET keywords so after querying single page displays 10 items. The thing is that I have to use ORDER BY for all matched rows not only for splited (and offsetted) 10 results in every query. In my script I have to have data grouped in two categories so i need to use UNION.

Look:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT n.name, n.id, n.type 
        FROM states AS n 
        WHERE
            n.lang = :lang AND 
                n.cat = 1
        ORDER BY
            n.id DESC
        LIMIT
            10 OFFSET :offset) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT n.name, n.id
        FROM states AS n 
        WHERE
            n.lang = :lang AND
                n.cat = 2
        ORDER BY
            n.id DESC
        LIMIT
            10 OFFSET :offset) 
    UNION) AS n ORDER BY n.type, n.name ASC
```

See that results are correctly ordered by name ASC but only for 10 results. If query match for eg. 100 rows always every 10 are sorted A-Z - it's not what I want. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Maybe I should get all matched rows and then split and sort it with PHP functions?

Comment: Don't put the LIMIT against your inner SELECTs then, put it against the outer SELECT; and why SORT both inner and outer SELECTs?

Comment: Note that this question has nothing to do with PHP, so shouldn't be tagged as PHP

Comment: Question editted. Maybe this problem needs a php solution. I dont know...

Comment: Sort it on the database - databases do sorting good

Comment: Please give my a clue: how.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.name, n.id, n.type 
  FROM states AS n 
 WHERE n.lang = :lang AND 
       n.cat IN (1, 2)
 ORDER BY n.type, n.name ASC
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset
```

Comment: Results from every category should be equal if possible.